# Pushing GeoJSON file from client to PostGIS on AWS

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgis, geojson

I am trying to push a GeoJSON file to PostGIS on AWS, and I am hitting an error I don't understand.

I have tried both of the following commands:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='postgres' host='host.rds.amazonaws.com' port='5432' user='user' password='pass'" "/Users/user/Desktop/output.json" -nln test_table -lco engine=GeoJSON

ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='postgres' host='host.rds.amazonaws.com' port='5432' user='user' password='pass'" "/Users/user/Desktop/output.json" -nln test_table
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to open datasource `/Users/reallymemorable/Desktop/output.json' with the following drivers.
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `MBTiles'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `REC'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `BNA'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `ESRIJSON'
  -> `TopoJSON'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `GPKG'
  -> `SQLite'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `PostgreSQL'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
  -> `XPlane'
  -> `DXF'
  -> `CAD'
  -> `Geoconcept'
  -> `GeoRSS'
  -> `GPSTrackMaker'
  -> `VFK'
  -> `PGDUMP'
  -> `OSM'
  -> `GPSBabel'
  -> `SUA'
  -> `OpenAir'
  -> `OGR_PDS'
  -> `WFS'
  -> `WFS3'
  -> `HTF'
  -> `AeronavFAA'
  -> `EDIGEO'
  -> `GFT'
  -> `SVG'
  -> `CouchDB'
  -> `Cloudant'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `ARCGEN'
  -> `SEGUKOOA'
  -> `SEGY'
  -> `XLS'
  -> `ElasticSearch'
  -> `Carto'
  -> `AmigoCloud'
  -> `SXF'
  -> `Selafin'
  -> `JML'
  -> `PLSCENES'
  -> `CSW'
  -> `VDV'
  -> `MVT'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `AVCBin'
  -> `AVCE00'
  -> `HTTP'
```

Are these MacOS drivers being referred to?  Or PostGIS drivers?  AWS drivers?  Is there something simply wrong with my ogr2ogr commands?